# Facebook SSO not working for first time in iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk, single-sign-on

I am facing one small issue, i have searched a lot however didn't got anything work. I am implementing Facebook SSO inside iPhone App. When i click on button in my app, it launches facebook application and after giving credentials username and password for facebook, it doesn't ask me authorization for my app. Infact it opens facebook page and never redirect to my app with authorization. This happens for first time only, however when user is logged in  previously inside facebook app, it always ask for authorization from second time.Please help me regarding this issues.